# How to implement the ERC777 token standard?

Tags: tokens, erc-777

Does anyone know how to correctly implement the new [ERC777 token standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/777)? I've been trying to create an ERC777 contract (see code below) but keep struggling with a couple of things.

1. According to the standard, recipient addresses must match the `ITokenRecipient` interface as returned by an [ERC-672](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/672) reverse lookup. Any idea how to do this?
2. There seems to be a fallback interface `ITokenFallback` that is not mentioned in the standard at all. How does 777 handle fallbacks (e.g. in case foreign tokens are sent to the contract)?
3. The standard requires the usage of `operatorData` and `userData` but doesn't really say what to do with these values. Is it sufficient to include this data in the events that are defined in the 777 interface?

My **ERC777 implementation** so far:

```
contract MyToken is EIP777 {

string public name;            
uint8 public decimals;               
string public symbol;  
uint256 public totalSupply;
mapping (address => uint256) balances;
mapping (address => mapping (address => bool)) authorizedOperators;

function send(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        Send(msg.sender, _to, _value, msg.sender, null, null);
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
}

function send(address _to, uint256 _value, _userData bytes) returns (bool success) {
    if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        Send(msg.sender, _to, _value, msg.sender, _userData, null);
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
}

function operatorSend(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value, bytes _userData, bytes _operatorData) returns (bool success) {
    if (balances[_from] >= _value && _value > 0 && isOperatorAuthorizedFor(msg.sender, _from) ) {
        balances[_to] += _value;
        balances[_from] -= _value;
        Send(_from, _to, _value, msg.sender, _userData, _operatorData);
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
}

function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
}

function authorizeOperator(address _operator, bool _authorized) public {
    authorizedOperators[msg.sender][_operator] = _authorized;
    AuthorizeOperator(msg.sender, _operator, _authorized);
}

function isOperatorAuthorizedFor(address _operator, address _tokenHoler) public constant returns (bool) {
    return authorizedOperators[_tokenHoler][_operator];
}

}
```

I did some research and stumbled upon [YogaToken](https://github.com/Giveth/yogatoken/blob/master/contracts/YogaToken.sol). However, it uses [ERC672](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/672) and a more complex implementation of `authorizedOperators` which adds `globallyAuthorizedOperators` and a `doSend()` function. It doesn't implement `ITokenRecipient`, either.

Comment: Did you check the official repository of reference implementation: https://github.com/jacquesd/eip777/blob/master/contracts/ReferenceToken.sol

Answer (score 4):

1) Matching the `ERC777TokensRecipient` interface is optional.
More specifically, one single ERC1820 registry is deployed on most Ethereum networks, always at the same address: 0x1820a4B7618BdE71Dce8cdc73aAB6C95905faD24.
The ERC1820 registry contains a mapping from addresses to contract addresses verifying the `ERC777TokensRecipient` interface. Those `ERC777TokensRecipient` contracts contain a `tokensToSend`  and a `tokensReceived` hook functions.
Every ERC777 transfer occurs in the following way:
- Step1: If the sender address is registered in ERC1820 registry the `tokensToSend` hook function is executed. If the sender address is not registered, this step is skipped.
- Step2: The sender and recipient balances are updated.
- Step3: If the recipient address is registered in ERC1820 registry the `tokensReceived` hook function is executed. If the recipient address is not registered, this step is skipped.

2) There's no fallback interface.

3) It is not specified in the standard, it depends on the implementation. The `data` field can contain information which will condition the validation/revert of the transaction depending on the business use case.
For example, the [implementation proposed by ConsenSys](https://github.com/ConsenSys/ERC1400/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC777/ERC777.sol) uses the `data` field to inject a certificate containing a signature of an authority verified on-chain thanks to an ecrecover operation.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenZeppelin 2.3.0](https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/t/openzeppelin-2-3/787) includes an ERC777 implementation.