# Safe way to make a payable function that accepts a ERC20 Token in a contract that didn't create that Token

Tags: contract-design, erc-20, payable

I have two contracts, contract A represents Token A, contract B is its own contract.
I users to call a contract B function by paying Token A to contract B, as if they were using a payable function, but by paying Token A instead of ETH.

Is making the user call token.approve() on contract A and then token.transferFrom() on contract B a safe solution or is there a pattern I should follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [ERC777](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-777) standard for your requirements.

It defines advanced features to interact with tokens. Namely, operators to send tokens on behalf of another address—contract or regular account—and send/receive hooks to offer token holders more control over their tokens.

this might help: [ERC777 with ERC20 backward compatibility](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97188/is-it-possible-to-trigger-an-erc777-receiver-hook-by-receiving-erc20-tokens/97189#97189) and [ERC777 implementation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/35635/how-to-implement-the-erc777-token-standard)